# Resize div in certain increments

Tags: html, css

Basically I want to increase the divs width depending on the page size but I want to increase the width by 100px at a time. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: To clarify - the `div`'s width is always the multiple of 100 that is "closest" to the page's size? In this case, is it the lower multiple of 100, the higher multiple of 100, or the nearest multiple of 100? (`ceil` vs `floor` vs `round`)

Comment: You might consider [using media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) and set breakpoints to define specific sizes.

Comment: This is a pure punt, but would `calc` be of any assistance in this? Something like 90% of screen width and then divided by 100 and rounded to an integer and then multiplied by 100?

Comment: @Martin I was thinking along those lines too, but the only way I could see you pulling this off is to use modulo or something like `parseInt`.  Parsing as an integer would require javascript obviously, and modulo was taken out of the spec for `calc`.  I don't see a way you can do his with just CSS and HTML

Answer (score 1):

Here's a really dirty way of doing it... but it is **PURE HTML AND CSS >:D**  This may not be a viable in all situations... but the general idea is to use a series of inline-block elements which get wrapped to the next line, but their parent is overflow-hidden to mask the fact that this is happening. A separate container can be used on top of these inline-block elements in order to hold actual content.

Example:

HTML:

```
<div class="modulo-fill">
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
    </p>
    <p>
      TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
    </p>
    <p>
      TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="fill"></div>
  <div class="fill"></div>
  <div class="fill"></div>
  <div class="fill"></div>
  <div class="fill"></div>
  <div class="fill"></div>
  <div class="fill"></div>
  <div class="fill"></div>
  <div class="fill"></div>
  <div class="fill"></div>
  <div class="fill"></div>
  <div class="fill"></div>
  <div class="fill"></div>
  <div class="fill"></div>
  <div class="fill"></div>
  <div class="fill"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.modulo-fill {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 0;
}
.modulo-fill > .content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.modulo-fill > .fill {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px; height: 100%;
  background-color: #800000;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gershy/hcmoq9et/3/

Try resizing the bottom-right box in jsfiddle to see the resize effect.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS media queries you can set "break points" that happen every 100px.

http://codepen.io/CKH4/pen/rxdeoV?editors=110
Here is the CSS:

```
.element {
  width: 100px;
}

@media (min-width: 200px) {
  .element {
    width: 200px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 300px) {
  .element {
    width: 300px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .element {
    width: 400px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .element {
    width: 500px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .element {
    width: 600px;
  }
}
```

And so on, and so on. This is a lot of code but it keeps your html markup clean.

This can be automated if you are using a CSS preprocessor. Here are some preprocessor examples.

Stylus:
http://codepen.io/CKH4/pen/VeXaEW?editors=110

```
for i in (2..40)
  @media (min-width: (i * 100px))
    .element
      width (i * 100px)
```

Sass:
http://codepen.io/CKH4/pen/vLRGqp?editors=110

```
@for $i from 2 through 40
  @media (min-width: ($i * 100px))
    .element
      width: ($i * 100px)
```

SCSS:
http://codepen.io/CKH4/pen/OMvNYo?editors=110

```
@for $i from 2 through 40 {
  @media (min-width: ($i * 100px)) {
    .element {
      width: ($i * 100px);
    }
  }
}
```

Less:
http://codepen.io/CKH4/pen/obqLgG?editors=110

```
.break-at-100(@i) when (@i > 1) {
  .break-at-100((@i - 1));
  @media (min-width: (@i * 100px)) {
    .element {
      width: (@i * 100px);
    }
  }
}

body {
  .break-at-100(40)
}
```